# How to iterate an ordered dictionary recursively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author a_id="a101">
        <first>Gambardella </first>
        <last> Matthew</last>
        <email> matthew@standford.org</email>
      </author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author a_id='a007'>
        <first>Galos</first>
        <last> Mike</last>
        <email>mike@gmail.com</email>
    </author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I have converted the file into a dictionary using the `xmltodict` module, which returns an ordered dictionary. This dictionary contains dictionaries within dictionary as value.

```
from xmltodict import parse
data=open(file_name).read().replace('\n', '')
xml_dict = parse(data)
```

Now, I want to print the `xml_dict` in recursive manner up to a given depth in a "key:: value" format.

Any one can tell me how to iterate this dictionary in recursive manner.

I have tried the code:

```
def print_dict(_dict):
   for k, v in _dict.items():
    if hasattr(v, 'items'):
           print_dict(v)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            print_dict(dict(i))
    else:
            print "(%s::%s)"%(k,v)
```

but with this code book tag goes missing.

So, what will be the solution for this.......

Comment: `elif isinstance(v, list):` and then below `print_dict(dict(i))`. Shouldn't that be simply `print v(i)`?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use an xml parser?

Comment: Please show what you would like the output to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're not using the `k` key value in your recursive cases. I don't know exactly how you want the output to look, but I suspect that you could make it work by adding print statements to the `if` and `elif` blocks.

Here's a version that make the output even nicer looking by adding an optional "indent" parameter:

```
def print_dict(_dict, indent=""):
    for k, v in _dict.items():
        if hasattr(v, 'items'):
            print "%s(%s::" % (indent, k)
            print_dict(v, indent + "  ")
            print "%s)" % indent
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            print "%s(%s::" % (indent, k)
            for i in v:
                print_dict(dict(i), indent + "  ")
            print "%s)" % indent
        else:
            print "%s(%s::%s)" % (indent, k, v)
```